# Cypress - There was an error reconnecting to the Chrome DevTools protocol

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, electron, cypress

I'm running a controlled test in cypress and after some tests, this error is randomly occurring in the electron browser:

> There was an error reconnecting to the Chrome DevTools protocol.
> Please restart the browser.

[image]

In google chrome it is running without errors, but in electron it is breaking.

I need to run in electron because of settings in AWS.

Comment: what version of cypress are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with version 12.12 and 12.13. I solved by downgrading to version 12.11.

I suspect the issue is caused by this PR https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/26573/files

Comment: Can confirm this is happening to me on 12.12

Downgrading to 12.11 no longer throws error.

Comment: I crated an issue https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/26900 . please if you have some logs or a simople reproducible case add it to the issue.

Comment: Me I have a test case but it's very complex and includes proprietary code. And anyway since the error happens randomly to me I can't find a test case to add to the issue. @Eric Crescioni, it would be appreciated if you share your test case. Otherwise Cypress team will close the issue.

Comment: Sorry - no time and my code is also proprietary - had to downgrade and keep going.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to latest Cypress version (12.9.0 > 13.2.0 at the time of writing) fixed the issue for me. I think Chrome had been updated automatically to the latest version (117.0.x), causing a breaking change.